# JPA @Query, avg of elements with limit

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

have anybody idea how to convert postgresql query

```
select avg(stock.price) from stock where (stock.name = 'some_name' and stock.date in (select stock.date from stock where stock.name = 'some_name' limit 10))
```

to JPA query with the @Query annotation?

Now I have some mess, but working mess:

```
public Double countStocksAvgToDateAndDaysAmount(String stockName, String date, Integer days) {
        List<StockEntity> stocksByNameTillDate = stockRepository.getStocksByNameTillDates(stockName,
                java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));
        Integer countDays = 0;
        Double sum = 0.0;
        Double avg = 0.0;
        for (StockEntity stock : stocksByNameTillDate) {
            countDays++;
            sum += stock.getPrice();
            if (countDays >= days) {
                break;
            }
        }
        avg = sum / countDays;
        return avg;
    }
```

where the function **stockRepository.getStocksByNameTillDates()** uses @Query

```
 @Query("select stock from StockEntity stock where ((stock.name like :name) and (stock.date <= :date))")
    public List<StockEntity> getStocksByNameTillDates(@Param("name") String name,@Param("date") Date date);
```

I think that is a little (or worse, more than little) sub-optimal.
I read that the JPA Query does not support something like **limit**.

Have anybody idea how to improve or make more optimal this code? I mean the way that the JPA do this for me instead of this class, not make more optimal my java code.

Comment: JPQL doesn't provide a way of specifying a limit on number of rows in a subquery.

Comment: Above I wrote 
"I read that the JPA Query does not support something like limit."
But thanks anyway for the response :)

Comment: JPA Query DOES support limiting ... just not on SUBQUERY ... as I wrote above

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You are correct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This might be help for you to get the 10 rows using the jpa query.

```
String hql = "SELECT avg(stock.price) from Stock stock where (stock.name = :stockName and stock.date in (select stock.date from stock where stock.name = :stockName))";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("stockName", "stockName");
List results = query.list();

// If you want to fetch only 10 rows then
query.setMaxResults(10); //it takes only an integer parameter
```